# What is the best approach on upgradation of a mule integration application from mule runtime 1.4 to 2.0 and java 8 to java 11?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mule-esb, mulesoft

I am currently involved in a project, that requires migration of 3.5 to 4.x, 4.14 is working fine. I am raising this question because, mule 2 is supporting Java 11, while mule recommended approach is to work on adoptopenjdk 8.0

https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/mule-runtime/mule-4.2.0-release-notes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear exactly what is the question, however migrating from Mule 4.1.x to 4.2.x doesn't require usually changes to applications. You are free to use Java 8 or 11, though 8 is recommended.

Comment: thanks @aled. I had some trouble loading up anypoint studio in linux with adoptjdk 11.

Comment: My comment was about running Mule Runtime 4.2.x. Studio 7 only supports Java 8 or AdoptOpenJDK 8 to startup. Once inside you should be able to select AdoptOpenJDK 11 to run Mule.

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade from 4.1 to 4.2 without changing the code or the java version. 
So the best approach to migrate would be to use the same configuration as in 4.1

Furthermore, it's a good practice to upgrade the connectors versions of your app.